# How to plot data from a DataFrame at multiple levels

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have the following set of data:

```
period_date_str NAME    AMOUNT1     
2022-09-30      A       10          
2022-09-30      B       15          
2022-09-30      C       20          
2022-10-30      A       9           
2022-10-30      B       12          
2022-10-30      C       14          
2022-11-30      A       8           
2022-11-30      B       9           
2022-11-30      C       4
```

I'm trying to plot AMOUNT1 in the same chart with different lines for each of the names that I have so each one of the names ends up being a different "legend name".

Thank you so much as this one is my first question in StackOverflow. I really appreciate your help.

I know I could group my DataFrame by date and then by each of the names on a one-on-one basiss. But I'm looking for a way to autmate this task so that, in the future, if I get a new name I don't need to modify my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [`seaborn.lineplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html) after converting your dates [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.lineplot(data=df.assign(date=pd.to_datetime(df['period_date_str'])),
             x='date', y='AMOUNT1', hue='NAME')
```

Output:

[image]

Or use a [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
(df.assign(date=pd.to_datetime(df['period_date_str']))
   .pivot(index='date', columns='NAME', values='AMOUNT1')
   .plot()
 )
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, that completely solved the problem. I even tried without sns and the second option works too.